# How to execute event handler only once in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm creating button which allows to enter post section. I'm checking if the body has class 'logged-in'. If test is false I want to create div container for message " You have to **logi in**" and append it to my section. **My problem:** Everytime when I click this button, new node is appended. 
 - How to invoke handler only once ?

```
if( !isOnline ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var divForLog = document.createElement('div'),
        linkElement = document.createElement('a');

    linkElement.setAttribute('href', 'http://domain/login');
    linkElement.text = "log in"

    divForLog.innerHTML = "You have to ";
    divForLog.appendChild(linkElement);

    document.getElementById('last_questions').appendChild(divForLog);
}
```

Comment: You can either give the div an ID and check for the ID before creating another one or you can remove the eventhandler from whatever you have it attached to `document.getElementById('YourElement').onclick = null;` . If you have it assigned to an element as an attribute you can remove the attribute `document.getElementById('YourElement').removeAttribute('onclick');`. Can you show what calls the function? Thank you. You can try:

Comment: You can remove `click` event from button after append.

Comment: Probably better to create your divForLog in your html markup, with the css 'display' attribute set to none, and then just show/hide when needed

Answer (score 1):

Try to set an attribute `id` to your `div` (`container` in my example) and when the user `click` check if the element with `id` already exist in document, if not add it :

```
if( !isOnline && document.getElementById('container').length==0) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var divForLog = document.createElement('div'),
        linkElement = document.createElement('a');

    linkElement.setAttribute('href', 'http://domain/login');
    linkElement.text = "log in"

    divForLog.innerHTML = "You have to ";
    divForLog.appendChild(linkElement);
    divForLog.setAttribute('id', 'container'); //Add id attribute

    document.getElementById('last_questions').appendChild(divForLog);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential solutions, but I'll only list a couple here.

**"Global"**

Create a variable `var loginShown` in the scope where the handler is created. Then, change the `! isOnline` check to `! isOnline && ! loginShown` in the if statement, and set `loginShown = true` once you've appended the div.

**Fiddle the DOM**

Depending on the other content of `#last_questions` you can simply test whether or not the login element has already been appended using:

```
if ( ! document.getElementById('last_questions').querySelector('div > a[href="http://domain/login"]' ) ) {
    ...
}
```

Failing that, you can do as @NewToJS mentioned in the comments and add an attribute to the parent (once the div has been appended) which you can test for, such as an ID or `data-` attribute.

**Unbind the Event**

Easier if you're using jQuery, as mentioned by @Pawel you can simply unbind the event once the div has been appended. Probably the cleanest solution, but also trickier to implement. It also depends what else the handler is doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery something you could do(from the documentation [.one | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/one/)).

```
$("#button" ).one( "click", function() {
      var divForLog = document.createElement('div'),
            linkElement = document.createElement('a');

        linkElement.setAttribute('href', 'http://domain/login');
        linkElement.text = "log in"

        divForLog.innerHTML = "You have to ";
        divForLog.appendChild(linkElement);

        document.getElementById('last_questions').appendChild(divForLog);
    });
```

However another way I could think of would be to use jQuery's

```
$('#last_questions').html(divForLog);
```

#### Update

If thats not an option(most likely, as the #last_questions div may contain other stuff), you can create a `<div id="log-in-alert"></div>` which will live inside the `#last_questions` and only replace the html in this

Hope I was able to help??